# Tilemill Export in MBTiles Format displaying infinite export time

Tags: maps, gis, mapbox, tilemill

I'm attempting to upload my map as an MBTile, and it is telling me that there are thousands of days remaining, though my map does not have enormous quantities of data. I've tried several different exports, and they have not exported any of the data after several hours.

This is my first time exporting in MBTiles format, and I hope to eventually upload my information to MapBox. Is there a step that I am missing?

Best,

Comment: Currently I am facing the same problem that you are describing, did you manage to solve it? I am thinking about performing the export step on public server or something that has higher processor capabilities more than my pc

Comment: yup, I had to select map 'Bounds', the answer below explains it in detail.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are cropping and setting zoom levels.

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/

> Select the map “Bounds”. This is the area of the map to be exported. By default the entire world is selected. If your map is allocated to a smaller region of the globe, you can save processing time and disk space by cropping to that area.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I was selecting the Bounds, but I still had too many zoom levels.